# How to insert to nested dictionary into dictionary in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Swift whose structure is `[String : [[String : String]]]`. I can initialize this dictionary with values, but whenever I try to insert new values into the dictionary or edit it at all, it simply doesn't change and also doesn't throw any errors. Here's sample code that I've tried:

```
@State var dict = ["ex": [["Key1": "Val1", "Key2": "Val2", "Key3": "Val3"]]]

func change() {
    let t = ["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3"]
    let key = "string"
        
    dict[key] = [[String:String]]()
    dict[key]?.append([String:String]())
    dict[key]?.append(t)
}
```

The function `change()` executes without error or crash, but doesn't change `dict` at all. I've also tried calling `dict[address] = [t]`, but it doesn't change anything either.

Is there something I'm missing or failing to call?

Comment: When I run your code, the contents of the dictionary are updated properly. How did you verify that `dict` isn't changed?

Comment: @mag_zbc I set breakpoints and inspect variables at runtime in Xcode, and I also printed `dict` after this function. Both showed it unchanged. I have remembered since posting this, however, that I'm running the beta version of Xcode, so that may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's behaving as expected. At the end of call to change(), content of dict is mentioned below. By stepping through the change() and printing in debug window, you can see value of dict after each step as it happens.

```
(lldb) p dict
([String : [[String : String]]]) $R10 = 2 key/value pairs {
  [0] = {
    key = "string"
    value = 2 values {
      [0] = 0 key/value pairs {}
      [1] = 3 key/value pairs {
        [0] = (key = "key3", value = "val3")
        [1] = (key = "key2", value = "val2")
        [2] = (key = "key1", value = "val1")
      }
    }
  }
   [1] = {
    key = "ex"
    value = 1 value {
      [0] = 3 key/value pairs {
        [0] = (key = "Key2", value = "Val2")
        [1] = (key = "Key1", value = "Val1")
        [2] = (key = "Key3", value = "Val3")
      }
    }
  }
}
```